opencv.js extreme slow loading also refresh problem with gc
I wanna explore little more opencv with JS but loading is so heavy
even not using or calling any funcs.
Any suggest - Maybe my computer is old...
Simple loader :
import {asyncLoad} from "./libs/helper"

export var test3 = () => {
    asyncLoad("./libs/adapter.js", () => {
        asyncLoad("./libs/opencv-4.10.0.js", () => {
                    console.log('test !!!!!')
                })
  })
}
test3()


